# How can I use the relationship one data series to predict the outcome of a second data series?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two data sets, series1 and series2. series1 is complete, and series2 is incomplete. I want to use series1 to predict the missing values in series2.

```
data= [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
data2= [100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400, 12800, np.nan, np.nan]
```

It is important to note that there is no relationship between series 1 and series 2

I have tried to use TensorFlow and Scikit-learn to predict the missing values in series2, but I have not been able to get good results. We could use LSTM and build a sequence of 8 and 2 with series 1, but when i apply the same to second series, the primary relationship with the data is for the first series only so the values are not correct. Scikit-learn requires both series for regression.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# define the input time series
data= [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]

# define the lookback window and output window
lookback_window = 8
output_window = 2

# create a StandardScaler object to scale the data
scaler = StandardScaler()

# preprocess and scale the data
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(data).reshape(-1, 1))
X, y = preprocess_data(scaled_data, lookback_window, output_window)

# define and train the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(lookback_window, 1)))
model.add(Dense(output_window))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=0)

# define the new time series
data1 = [100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400, 12800]

# preprocess and scale the new data
scaled_new_data = scaler.transform(np.array(new_data).reshape(-1, 1))
new_X = np.array(scaled_new_data[-lookback_window:]).reshape((1, lookback_window, 1))

# make predictions for the next two values (of the new series)
prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(model.predict(new_X))
print(prediction)
```

The output predictions are way off and not surprising [[ 544.34814 1022.2846 ]]

How to approach this problem using machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a single example (x = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256], y = [512, 1024]) and repeating it 100 times during training so the network might be learning to always output the same answer.

To prevent your model from learning to memorize you will have to either increase the number of examples in the training set or decrease the number of parameters of the model (why 32 LSTM units?). Possibly both.

If you can make the assumption that the values in the sequence will always be the result of a linear operation with the previous value it could be better to ditch LSTM and use a simple linear Auto Regressive model.

If you can't make any assumption about the pattern of the sequences it might not be possible to train a decent machine learning model, even if you give it many examples (training and test data have to come from the same probability distribution, and training data has to be representative enough so the model can learn this distribution).